# Hyperlink doesn't work when animation effect is added (CSS, HTML)

Tags: html, css, animation

I did a linear animation effect to animate the border around the words"click to enter". When I tried to make words hyperlinked, it only works at a few seconds after I refresh the page (before the animation starts). Later when I hover over the words, there is no hyperlink directing to another page.

Here's the code for the animation:

```css
.center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

p {
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 70px;
  border: 7px solid transparent;
  padding: 5px;
  text-decoration: line-through;
  text-align: center;
}

p::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: -7px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  background: transparent;
  border: 7px solid transparent;
}

p:hover::before {
  animation: myframes 1s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes myframes {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top-color: black;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    border-top-color: black;
    border-right-color: black;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: transparent;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-top-color: black;
    border-right-color: black;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: transparent;
  }
}

p::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: -7px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  background: transparent;
  border: 7px solid transparent;
}

p:hover::after {
  animation: myframes2 1s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes myframes2 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top-color: transparent;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: black;
  }
  50% {
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    border-top-color: transparent;
    ;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-color: black;
    border-left-color: black;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-top-color: transparent;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-color: black;
    border-left-color: black;
  }
}
```

```html
<p><a href="content.html">Click to Enter</a></p>
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Can you add your HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the pseudo element is positioned above the `a`, simply adjust `z-index` to fix this:

```css
.center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

p {
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 70px;
  border: 7px solid transparent;
  padding: 5px;
  text-decoration: line-through;
  text-align: center;
  z-index:0;
}

p::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: -7px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  background: transparent;
  border: 7px solid transparent;
  z-index:-1;
}

p:hover::before {
  animation: myframes 1s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes myframes {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top-color: black;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    border-top-color: black;
    border-right-color: black;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: transparent;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-top-color: black;
    border-right-color: black;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: transparent;
  }
}

p::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: -7px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  background: transparent;
  border: 7px solid transparent;
  z-index:-1;
}

p:hover::after {
  animation: myframes2 1s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes myframes2 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top-color: transparent;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: black;
  }
  50% {
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    border-top-color: transparent;
    ;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-color: black;
    border-left-color: black;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-top-color: transparent;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-color: black;
    border-left-color: black;
  }
}
```

```html
<p><a href="content.html">Click to Enter</a></p>
```

By the way, you can simplify you code using gradient like below:

```css
p {
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 70px;
  border: 7px solid transparent;
  padding: 5px;
  text-decoration: line-through;
  text-align: center;
  background:
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) padding-box,
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,#000 50%,transparent 50.5%) 0 0 border-box;
  background-size:auto,0 0;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  transition:1s all;
}
p:hover {
  background-size:auto,200% 200%;
}
```

```html
<p><a href="content.html">Click to Enter</a></p>
```